# Parcel stuck at customs. Further instruction should be requested from "Buyer" or from "Seller"?

Tags: taxes, legal, ecommerce, south-africa, customs

I have an issue where a package is stuck at the logistic company customs offices because the seller has apparently misdeclared the content value. I am not going to pay the fine they want me to pay so now they want know what they should do with the parcel. **Should they not be asking this from the seller** as I have explicitly told them I have no intention of paying any misdeclaration charge on the parcel.

I am worried that if **"I"** give them any instruction regarding the parcel, it will be legally binding against myself (e.g. if I say they must ship it back to the seller, they might send the shipping invoice to me and not carry the cost on them self or the seller).

I am more than happy to just stick it out and keep telling them to contact the Seller, but just wanted a bit more *clarity with regards to if I will be legally/contractually binded to any instruction I give them and also if this instruction is not supposed to come from the seller since the parcel is a **stopped state**.*

Finally, if you have purchased an item on Ebay/Amazon/Aliexpress or the like, *are you immediately considered to be the owner of the purchased product even if you have not received or signed for it*.

I also wouldn't want any unneccessary action I take to affect my refund request

EDIT - A bit more information from the taxman:

> Item bought for: ZAR1900 (around $102 at the time of purchase)
>
> Expedited Shipping cost: ZAR400 (around $20 at the time of purchase)
>
> Duties + logistics administration if proper declaration was done:
> ZAR390
>
> Duties + logistics administration due to misdeclaration: ZAR960

So I would have to spend an additional ZAR570 due to the misdeclaration. I would rather cut my loses and ask a for refund then reorder the item as I am not in a rush to receive it.

I paid by through Paypal so will lodge a refund request if this is not resolved in a timely manner.

Comment: How sure are you that this is a legitimate customs authority asking you to pay? (the other option being it is someone affiliated with the "seller" and the whole transaction is a scam)

Comment: yoozer8. Might be, but I purchased based on reviews. The parcel is at customs based on tracking info received from the Logistics Company (also communicating via legit domain email addresses). I think the seller was trying to save me some customs duties by undervalueing the items even though I never asked them to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure if it changes the answer but can you say how much the goods actually cost, how much the declared value was, how much the fine is, and how much return shipping might cost? Also did you pay for the item with a credit card or other payment that lets you do a chargeback?

Comment: When you don't fetch the parcel it is lilkeley sent back. How did you pay? The seller may not be willing to refund your money after you caused trouble.

Comment: Freiheit. I have added the edits.

Comment: Bernhard Döbler. Payment was done via Paypal. Undfortunately the seller is also not replying to my messages with regards to the misdeclaration so I will use that as evidence for my due diligence when I finally decide to lodge the request with Paypal.